# Removing the square roots from a numerator and a denominator, why? (sequnence limits)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, square-numbers

I really don't understand calculus and limits... everything seems pointless, i mean why are we doing the things we do here?? What's the point of dividing the whole expression by the highest power of n? When do we use that?

Also i have a picture here of two different exercises which i totally don't understand.. in the first exercise he removes the square roots from the numerator, in the second he removes it from the denominator. What's the point of this??

I made an image for you to better see the problem:

$ \lim \frac{\sqrt{(n^2)+n}-n}1 = \frac{\sqrt{(n^2)+n}-n}1 * \frac{\sqrt{(n^2)-n}+n}{\sqrt{(n^2)+n}+n} $

and

$ \lim \frac{1}{\sqrt{9n^2+5n}-3n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{9n^2+5n}-3n}* \frac{\sqrt{9n^2+5n}+3n}{\sqrt{9n^2+5n}+3n} $

Comment: Maybe your problem demands so. I think you must elaborate. It's not clear.

Comment: The exercise says to find the limit, that's all.

Comment: $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$ we do this because on left hand side (naively it's $\infty-\infty$) it is not at all obvious that sequence goes to $0$, but on RHS it is painfully obvious. You do the other way around to simplify denominator - it sometimes simplifies whole fraction to very nice form and often it's easier to deal with them when denominator is rational.

Comment: It's better if you post the question here instead of linking to the image.

Comment: the question: http://i.imgur.com/gynDgpW.png i'm sorry but it's easier to copy the exercise to paint and edit (less time consuming)

Comment: @PLE So the point is to make everything easier so we can see see/calculate the limit?

Comment: @JohnDale As far as I know this kind of computation is considered useful tricky algebraic manipulations which are done for many purposes, but primary object is to either simplify the expression or transform it into a form which helps us to see our point

Comment: @tatan ok i edited my question can you please help me?

Comment: @PLE I see, and what rule is valid for sequences that have trigonometric expression inside? For example:

$ \lim \frac{sin(\frac{\Pi*n}7)}n $

Comment: Mathematics is full of tricks, manipulation and intuition. You can do these to get the desired answer. If you asked me why I will do this then I would answer that my intuition and experience tell me to do so. So, you better know all the tricks and have enough experience (practice) for solving problems. :)

Comment: @tatan So can you tell me a trick that i can use in 

$ \lim \frac{sin(\frac{\Pi*n}7)}n $ ?

Comment: I don't know why you are intending the question to me. What makes you think that I know all of calculus. You may post this question so that all can try solving it.